# Python EBNF Syntax to Match a Decorator

Tags: python, ebnf, lib2to3

I have a very large project where I need to move some modules from `bar` to `foo.bar`, and subsequently update all functions calls to reflect new location.

This works fine against function calls, but I am having problems building a pattern to match decorators.

The code I like to match is::

```
  from unittest.mock import patch

  @patch('bar')
  def func(self, patcher):
      ...
```

I would like to turn the patch above to `@patch('foo.bar')`.

My current pattern matches `patch` when it is a function call, but not when used as a decorator::

```
class FixRenameMockPatch(fixer_base.BaseFix):

    PATTERN = """
    power<
        'patch' args=trailer< '(' [any] ')' >
    >
    """

    def transform(self, node, results):
        ...
```

I am really struggling to understand the grammar on https://docs.python.org/3.8/reference/grammar.html so my fixers has largely been based on the source code of `lib2to3`.

How do I write the pattern above to match all uses of `patch`, including a decorator and a context manager?  And a full qualified use of patch, such as `mock.patch` or `unittest.mock.patch`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this

```
PATTERN = "decorator< '@' 'patch' '(' [any] ')' any* >"
```

or alternatively

```
PATTERN = """
    decorator< '@' 'patch' '(' [any] ')' any* >
    | decorator< '@' dotted_name< 'mock' '.' 'patch' > '(' [any] ')' any* >
    """
```

if you want to match `@mock.patch` too.

There is [a script](http://svn.python.org/projects/sandbox/trunk/2to3/scripts/find_pattern.py) (written in Python2, [Py3 version here](https://gist.github.com/mahmoudimus/459a5f434832290f92cbe00292e1f638)) to parse your file and shows the parsed pattern, which I find useful. For example, you create `test.py` as

```
from unittest.mock import patch

@patch('bar')
def func(self, patcher):
    print('foo')
```

Then run `find_pattern.py`, hit enter until the line you want to parse is shown, then enter some character (y in the case below), and hit enter to show the parsing result:

```
$ python find_pattern.py -f test.py
' unittest.mock'

'from unittest.mock import patch'

'from unittest.mock import patch\n'

"\n@patch('bar')\n"
y
decorator< '@' 'patch' '(' "'bar'" ')' '\n' >
```

Comment: lifesaver. here's a gist for it for python3: https://gist.github.com/mahmoudimus/459a5f434832290f92cbe00292e1f638

Comment: Glad to hear that this was helpful  I also added the link to your gist to the answer.